# Is the word "the" necessary here?

Tags: grammaticality

Please correct my mistake (if it is) in the below sentence:
"SS-Computing: A New Method for Calculating smth Based on (the) variation of smth else"
Could you tell me if I must put "the" before "variation" or not?
Thanks.

Comment: Yea, I am writing a paper and I am not sure if I it is better to use "the" or not in the title of my paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this looks like a scholarly paper title to me, articles are not usually omitted there, as compared to newspaper articles (where a special set of rules is used, called [Headlinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)). Therefore I would leave the article as is.

Answer (score 0):

For a title, I think either way is acceptable--omitting the "the" or not before "variation *of* smth." If it were "variation *in*," which suggests there may be more than one source of variation, it would be more appropriate to omit the "the."